# Disk drives not detected by Windows installation but are detected by Bios

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, hardware-detection

I just built myself a new computer and I'm having issues installing Windows 7 Professional (legit copy) on my RAID array I setup.

**Specs**:

- [Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 rev. 4.0](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4672#ov)
- [AMD FX-8350 Vishera 4.0GHz](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819113284)
- 2x [WL Ultra-Fast 600GB 10000RPM 32MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5"](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA5AD2097073)
- Antec 1000W Fully Modular PSU
- 2x [Radeon R7 260x](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/r7) Crossfire

**Installation**:

- Hard-drives are plugged into the 0/1 SATA slots as indicated by the manual for setting up RAID.
- Windows 7 is loaded onto a bootable USB flash-drive (Originally was using a DVD-RW but it was causing grief as it wasn't detecting any drivers)
- On boot-up I hit Ctrl+F to open the RAID interface. I added my RAID array as RAID 0 (see steps below).
- I then reboot (as suggested by RAID setup) and load Win7 bootable USB. I hit next after choosing Locale settings, and click install, It shows the RAID drive unallocated (1200GB) I choose advanced options and *New*, the RAID drive has now disappeared and no longer visible. Next is no longer selectable.
- At this point I press Shift+F10 to bring up command prompt. I type *diskpart* and press enter. It sits there never loading. So I hit Ctrl+C and exit the command prompt.
- At this point I reboot and attempt to load again, nothing is appearing. I remove the RAID array and attempt this way, still nothing.
- I attempt to load Drivers, I find drivers, load them and either nothing still appears or I get an error message *"No new devices found."*

**RAID Setup**:

- I pressed to *Defined LD* I Pressed Ctrl+C to create the array, set both Hard-drives as part of the RAID0 array with default settings otherwise.
- Ctrl+Y to define name as *MasterRaid0*, Ctrl+Y again to set size to 1200GB, and CTRL+Y again to finish creation.
- I view the RAID array afterwards and it shows it with 2 Hard-drives and health as *Functional*

**Other details**:

I had Windows 8 installed successfully but it was giving crappy generic BSOD errors "CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED" frequently so I tried going back to Windows 7. The Windows 8 was installed using the same DVD-RW that the Windows 7 install disk was on (which was giving me problems) so I figured that it might have been the cause of the BSODs.

**Question**:

How do I get Windows 7 installed using RAID when the Drives won't appear in the installation or in diskpart? (The motherboard/bios detects it by the way).

I've been doing non-stop Google searches to attempt to troubleshoot this, I've had nothing but problems. I tried to put my other computer's hard-drive in and boot from that but it was unsuccessful (froze after bios/raid screens). The harddrive from the other computer also wasn't detected which makes me believe it's not the hard-drives. I put the Disk-Drive in the SATA-0 slot to test the port and it worked, so I don't think it's the SATA ports on the board either.

I'm out of ideas, search results, and patients. Is there anything someone can think of that might help? Anything? I've waited 3 days (about to be a 4th tonight) on this dang thing. I'm going to attempt to boot my old computer up with the new drives and format them inside windows and see if that makes them visible to Win installation and diskpart again.

Alternatively I tried to install windows 7 without RAID and also tried to install Windows 8 again from USB with RAID. Both were unsuccessful. Both could no longer detect the drives. I tried adding the gigabyte RAID and SATA drivers during installation, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the hard-drives is defective. The reason I didn't detect it sooner is because if you have it plugged in, it manages to bog-down the whole system. Booting during bios slows down, all drives fail to be detected, etc.

I'm requesting an RMA from the retailer and this should solve the problem. I'm glad it's not the motherboard haha.

Answer (score 1):

I guessed your motherboard disk interface is too new that Windows 7 installation source don't have driver to support it.

Please download the Gigabyte motherboard Windows 7 Preinstall driver from web (depend on model), during Windows 7 installation when you see the disk un-allocated, click "Load Driver" select the download driver path (e.g. USB path).  Once it is done the installation should be able to continue.

Comment: Will it be labelled specifically as Windows 7 Preinstall drivers? Because I download the 3 RAID/Sata drivers I found on the Gigabyte site for my board and they weren't working. So they don't work or I missed the ones that were specifically for Win7 Preinstall?

Comment: Hmmm yeah I had them downloaded all along. It says to boot from a floppy disk so I guess I'll try my external and do that though I doubt it'll make a difference. I'll let you know later tonight if it works.